# An own dialog with ImageButton

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

The Dialog start after start the app! (OWN DIALOG) But when I add an ImageButton to the Dialog the App does crash but I want to use my own dialog xml file and my own designed imagebutton

Here is my code:

```
public class MenueActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    ImageButton btnverstanden;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menue);

        btnverstanden = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.verstanden);

        Context mContext = this.getApplicationContext();
        mPrefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("myAppPrefs", 0);

        if(getFirstRun()) {

            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog_tutorial);

            btnverstanden.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            setRan();
            dialog.show();
        }
    }

    public boolean getFirstRun() {
        return mPrefs.getBoolean("firstRun", true);
    }

    public void setRan() {
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = mPrefs.edit();
        edit.putBoolean("firstRun", false);
        edit.apply();
    }

}
```

thx when someone help me I dont understand this and I am an beginner

Comment: Post your logcat. Did you define your button in the dialog layout? Can you post your layout?

Comment: yes i define the button in the dialog layout

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference @Pztar

Comment: post your XML layouts please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `ImageButton btnverstanden;` is on `R.layout.activity_menue`, you cannot add this `ImageButton` to Dialog, if this button is on `R.layout.activity_dialog_tutorial` initialize this inside the Dialog.

Remove this:

```
btnverstanden = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.verstanden);
```

With this:

```
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog_tutorial);
        ImageButton btnverstanden = (ImageButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.verstanden);  //<---init here

        btnverstanden.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Bro, you are the best! @W4R10CK

Comment: @Jordie, seems that i'll code ur whole project.  hahaha just kidding.

Answer (score 0):

You said you got `NullPointException:ImageButton.setOnClickListener`, which means that `btnverstanden` is null.

ImageButton `btnverstanden` is in your dialog layout, but you init in your mian layout `R.layout.activity_menue`,so I guess it's why you got the exception.

Maybe you should write like this:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog_tutorial);
View view = getLayoutInflate().inflate(R.layout.activity_dialog_tutorial,null);
btnverstanden = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.verstanden);
```